# Determine if two LR(1) action/goto tables always produce the same derivation

Tags: algorithms, formal-grammars, lr-k

I am experimenting with implementing minimal LR(1) algorithms/techniques, but I find it very difficult to verify the correctness of what I've implemented.

Is there a fast algorithm to determine if two LR(1) action/goto tables accept the same language, given that they use the same grammar rules?

Or preferably a stronger (but easier to falsify) test, that two LR(1) action/goto tables will always produce the same derivation for any input.